# ReactiveCocoa - Subscribe to the second signal, if the first completes with no value

Tags: reactive-cocoa

Imagine I have two signals: a cheap one and an expensive one:

```
RACSignal *localSignal;      // Cheap signal. Sends object without network request 
                             // if possible, otherwise completes immediately. 

RACSingal *networkSignal;    // Expensive one. Always sends data, 
                             // but requires expensive network operation.
```

Now I want to create a signal, which sends value from the first signal, if any, or subscribe to the second one and sends data from that one.

The following solution almost gives me what I want, but it always subscribes to the second, expensive signal, even if a value from the first signal is taken, and the second signal's value is ignored.

```
[[localDataSignal concat:networkDataSignal] take:1];
```

Is there a way to solve the problem efficiently?

Comment: I feel like this shouldn't subscribe to the expensive signal, and that this is a disposal bug. Might wanna file an issue on RAC's project.

Comment: Just found the problem. See my answer bellow. I thick, since local signal works in the same thread on which it is subscribed to, take:1 doesn't even has a chance to dispose the whole sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found what was the problem. The local signal used the same thread where it was created and called on:

```
RACSignal *localSignal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {
    NSLog(@"Perfoming local operation");
    [subscriber sendNext:@"local value"];
    [subscriber sendCompleted];
    return nil;
}];
```

As I see the problem (I am not sure for 100%) take:1 don't even had a chance to dispose the concatenated network signals. But if I schedule the local signal on a different than the main thread scheduler, then take:1 works as expected -- it breaks the chain, after it gets the first value.

In simple words this snippet works:

```
[[[localSignal deliverOn:[RACScheduler scheduler]] concat:networkSignal] take:1]
```

It gives me exactly what I wanted: local signal's value, if any, or subscribes to the network signal and gives me its value. In case the local signal sends value, the network signal never gets subscribed.

The rule of thumb is to check the thread the signal works on, then take:1 should do its work as expected.

**Update**: `-deliveOnMainThread` also gives `-take:` the chance to dispose the queue.

Comment: Ah I see. A design flaw of RAC 2 is that events sent synchronously during subscription will always happen before any chain can be broken through disposal. So in this case it's not the thread per se, it's that `localSignal` sends events sunchronously at subscription. You don't need to `deliverOn:` a different scheduler, you could even deliver on `mainThreadScheduler`. Any `deliverOn:` produces a GCD hop which adds asynchrony. Alternatively, `subscribeOn:` would work, or even `delay:0`.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought as well, when I tried. Also you are right, that deliverOnMainThread works as well. Thank you for pointing the take:1 problem out, so I could play with it a little.

Comment: Actually one problem, that I can see with that approach is that signal performs asynchronously, even if it is scheduled in main thread. In case if I use it for UI operations, for example for UICollectionViewCell with image, theoretically when I apply the the signal with image to the cell, the collection view gets its cell, and then signal applies the image to it. If it happens in different sync frames, I will see blinks. With my particular example I don't see that, apparently, because I return cell and signal applies the image in the same sync frames.

Comment: I just added an answer with an approach that should fix the main thread delivery you're describing. Now that I'm writing this, another approach is to use `subscribeOn:` on the network signal, which might let the `take` work too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
- (RACSignal *)catchTo:(RACSignal *)signal;
```

Like this:

```
[[localSignal catchTo:networkSignal] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    // If localSignal sends error, networkSignal will be subscribed.
}];
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. The problem is that the local signal doesn't send any error. It whether completes or returns a value and then completes. Therefore I need to see if, the first signal completes, but if I have no values from it, then I want to be subscribed to the second signal (expensive one).

Comment: It sounds for me that the local signal should send an error in case it cannot send next value, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ugly, but prior to the network signal, concat an empty signal that has a delay. I haven't tried this, but it should introduce the asynchrony needed to allow the `take` to prevent `networkSignal` from being subscribed to in the case where `localSignal` sends a value. This approach doesn't effect the deliver of the value of `localSignal`.

```
[[RACSignal concat:@[
    localSignal,
    [[RACSignal empty] deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler],
    networkSignal
] take:1]
```

Alternative to `deliverOn:`, you might consider `delay:` if that makes this code easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you! I found that I was wrong, even if I deliver the signal to the main scheduler, it still works synchronously. I just simulated some example: https://db.tt/th1oXRWO. Also if I deliver the signal to the different scheduler, logically enough, it will set the value after the cell is returned: https://db.tt/N89bOO1W. On screenshots you can see kind of synthetic test, but I also tried it with real UICollectionView and real cells -- image is set synchronously before the data source returns the cell. I should really say you thank you for point to the right direction.

Comment: Just tried -- `delay:0` works the same as delivering signal to different thread.